# If time col is null then replace with 00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time, null

I am working on a hospital database and table details are

```
Patient number     Dischargeto             Date           Time

212              Hospital1            16/10/2018      14:00:00
212              Hospital2            18/10/2018      10:00:00
212              Hospital3            20/10/2018      18:00:00
212              Home                 22/10/2018      10:00:00
213              Hostpital1           11/11/2018      11:00:00
213              Death                14/11/2018      18:00:00
214              Hospital 1           28/12/2011      14:00:00
214              Home                 05/01/2012      NULL

Info:
Final destination of the patient 
212 is Home
213 is Death
214 is home
```

I want patients whose final destination is not death 
so I wrote this query

```
select * 
from 
(select
Patient number, DischargeTo, Date, Time,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Patientnumber order by Date desc, Time desc) as testcount

from tablename) abc
where   testcount = 1
and 
DischargeTo not like '%Death%'
```

results are not correct where time is null. I want to convert
if time is null then it converts to 00:00:00 
 and so the sorting could be corrected.

Thanks behorehand

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without knowing which specific DBMS you're using. If you read the description of the [tag:sql], it strongly suggests that you add a tag for that DBMS whenever using the SQL tag, as syntax and functionality between them varies. Please [edit] your post to add the tag for the specific DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

make your date time as valid sql datetime before sorting.

```
select * 
from 
(select
Patient number, DischargeTo, Date, Time,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Patientnumber order by cast(concat(RIGHT([Date],4) + '' + SUBSTRING([Date],4,2) + '' + LEFT([Date],2), ' ', [Time]) as datetime)) as testcount

from tablename) abc
where   testcount = 1
and 
DischargeTo not like '%Death%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had switch the day and month in the date string as the datetime conversion was giving out-of-bounds error. Try the following:

```
with hospitaldt(PatientId, DischargeTo, dt) as
(
select PatientId, DischargeTo, convert(datetime, concat(Date, " ", isnull(Time, "00:00:00")))
from hospital
)
select t1.PatientId, t1.DischargeTo, t1.dt
from hospitaldt t1
where t1.dt =
(
select max(t2.dt)
from hospitaldt t2
where t2.DischargeTo not like "%Death%"
and t2.PatientId = t1.PatientId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "death" only happens once, so you don't need to look for the *final status*.  Just check for whether death is ever there:

```
select patient_number
from tablename
group by patient_number
having sum(case when dischargeto = 'Death' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```